# DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql

Tags: pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a problem with inserting data from dataframe to postgresql database using already existing table

```
sql_engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pw@host:port/db_name', echo=False)
connection = sql_engine.raw_connection()
combined_df.to_sql('clients', connection, schema = 'direct' index=False, if_exists='append')
```

And after that there is a database error:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '
        SELECT
            name
        FROM
            sqlite_master
        WHERE
            type IN ('table', 'view')
            AND name=?;
        ': syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 8:             AND name=?;
                              ^
```

Comment: My guess it has to do with `connection = sql_engine.raw_connection()`. Try what is shown here [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). Something like `combined_df.to_sql('clients', con=sql_engine, schema = 'direct' index=False, if_exists='append')`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver if i try this way then there is an error ```AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'```

Comment: I cannot replicate that error, it works for me. Though I did notice I did not add the missing comma after `schema = 'direct'`, though that would throw a different error. You need to **add to your question** the complete changed code you tried.